# Cannot inject two fields of same interface when using @Profile annotation on bean configuration method

Tags: java, spring

I use Spring 5.1.4.RELEASE and have a trouble injecting two fields of same interface via constructor when using @Profile annotation on bean configuration methods. I have a simple *Publisher* component like follows:

```
@Component
public class Publisher {

    private final MyClient prodClient;
    private final MyClient testClient;

    @java.beans.ConstructorProperties({"prodClient", "testClient"})
    public Publisher(MyClient prodClient, MyClient testClient) {
        this.prodClient = prodClient;
        this.testClient = testClient;
    }

}
```

When I mark whole configuration with **@Profile** annotation, then it works as expected:

```
@Profile(Profiles.MY_CLIENT)
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyClient prodClient() {
        return new HttpClient("prod.client.channel");
    }

    @Bean
    public MyClient testClient() {
        return new HttpClient("test.client.channel");
    }
}
```

The above configuration is OK, but the problem occurs when I want to have the **@Profile** annotation **only on some methods inside a configuration class**:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    @Profile(Profiles.MY_CLIENT)
    @Bean
    public MyClient prodClient() {
        return new HttpClient();
    }

    @Profile(Profiles.MY_CLIENT)
    @Bean
    public MyClient testClient() {
        return new HttpClient();
    }

    // some other beans...
}
```

Then I get an error during startup:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.Publisher required a bean of type 'com.test.MyClient' that could not be found.
```

**UPDATE:**
It's solved. It was my mistake. I had two more bean methods annotated with different @Profile for integration tests, but they had the same name for production code (annotated with *Profiles.MY_CLIENT* profile):

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    @Profile(Profiles.MY_CLIENT)
    @Bean
    public MyClient prodClient() {
        return new HttpClient();
    }

    @Profile(Profiles.MY_CLIENT)
    @Bean
    public MyClient testClient() {
        return new HttpClient();
    }

    // ... other beans

    @Profile(Profiles.MOCK_MY_CLIENT)
    @Bean
    public MyClient prodClient() {
        return new MockClient();
    }

    @Profile(Profiles.MOCK_MY_CLIENT)
    @Bean
    public MyClient testClient() {
        return new MockClient();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, If you try to inject a list of this components?
Something like

```
public Publisher(List<MyClient> clients) {

}
```

and in the client implementations you set a flag that could be useful to know when you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

In this code here:

```
@java.beans.ConstructorProperties({"prodClient", "testClient"})
public Publisher(MyClient prodClient, MyClient testClient) {
    this.prodClient = prodClient;
    this.testClient = testClient;
}
```

Try using the @Autowired annotation on the parameters instead:

```
public Publisher(@Autowired MyClient prodClient, @Autowired MyClient testClient) {
    this.prodClient = prodClient;
    this.testClient = testClient;
}
```